# Reinitialize Slick after successful change value of select option, all good except buttons prev next

Tags: jquery, slick.js

I'm trying to reinitialize slick after successful change value of select option, photos (thumbs and big images) change correctly but prev and next buttons of thumbs slider not working correctly. If i press next button slider of thumbs don't go on last item, only until the one before last. And then if i press previous button slider of thumbs goes to first otem and not to previous... slider of big images works correctly...

my code to reinitialize is this

```
$("#product-thumbs").slick("unslick");
$("#product-thumbs .item").remove();
$("#product-thumbs").html(htmlThumbs);
$("#product-thumbs").slick({
    dots: false,
    infinite: false,
    speed: 300,
    adaptiveHeight: true,
    vertical: true,
    horizontal: false,
    verticalSwiping: true,
    prevArrow: "<span class=\'slick-up\'></span>",
    nextArrow: "<span class=\'slick-down\'></span>",
    slidesToShow: 3,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    asNavFor: "#product-big",
    focusOnSelect: true
});
```

and

```
<div class="thumbs" id="product-thumbs">
     <div class="item"><img src="XXX" alt=""></div>
     <div class="item"><img src="XXX" alt=""></div>
     <div class="item"><img src="XXX" alt=""></div>
     <div class="item"><img src="XXX" alt=""></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Where is your AJAX call?!

Comment: No AJAX call now... I just use a check when my select option change value. When its change value i change photos of slider correctly. My slider unslick and slick again correctly but buttons prev and next of thumbs slider not working correctly...